# Taking only particular subsets and doing calculations

Tags: list-manipulation

I have subsets formed from a list using the `Subsets` command and want to do a particular calculation, lets say subtraction using the `Subtract` command only with the sets I want.
For example,

```
m = {4, 5, 3, 2, 8};

Subsets[m, {2}]

{{4, 5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 8}, {5, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 8}, {3, 2}, {3, 8}, {2, 8}}
```

From this list first I want to take the subsets  that contains 4 and do subtraction. Then I want to take all subsets that contain 5, including `{4,5}` and do subtraction and so on.

Comment: (Sub)sets are not ordered while subtraction is non-commutative.  Are you sure this is exactly what you meant (or that it is subtraction that you want)?

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question, one possibility:

```
Select[Subsets[m, {2}], MemberQ[#, 4] &]
Select[Subsets[m, {2}], MemberQ[#, 4 | 5] &]
Select[Subsets[m, {2}], MemberQ[#, 4 | 5] && FreeQ[#, 8] &]
```

giving

> (*{{4, 5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 8}}
>
> {{4, 5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 8}, {5, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 8}}
>
> {{4, 5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 2}}
>
> *)

Comment: And then if you want to apply subtraction to each subset you can simply use the shorthand for Apply: Subtract@@@Select[Subsets[m, {2}], MemberQ[#, 4] &]

Answer (score 0):

Sets are not ordered, so the (non-commutative) subtraction can be done either as `a - b` or `b - a` for the subset `{a, b}`.  Keeping this in mind, here's a solution that computes all results in one go:

```
m = {4, 5, 3, 2, 8};
ss = Subsets[m, {2}]
g = GatherBy[Join[ss, Reverse /@ ss], First]
Apply[Subtract, g, {2}]

(* ==> 
  {{-1, 1, 2, -4}, {2, 3, -3, 1}, {1, -5, -1, -2}, {-6, -2, -3, -1}, {4, 3, 5, 6}}
*)
```

This gives results for subsets that contain the following elements, respectively:

```
g[[All, 1, 1]]

(* ==> {4, 5, 3, 2, 8} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Special thanks to Belisarius.
```

Based on his idea I had written the below code

```
list = {4, 10, 16, 7, 18}

c = Subsets[Range[Length@list], {2}];

m = Table[Cases[c, {_, i} | {i, _}], {i, Length@list}]

s[{i_, j_}] := Subtract[list[[i]], list[[j]]];

Table[Map[s, m[[f]]], {f, Length@m}]
```